# Get and change hashmapvalues

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an HashMap myHashMap, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, UserContact> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, UserContact>(); // first string = username
    fillHasmap(myHashMap); // a method to fill my hashmap
    HashMap<String, String> usernameAndType = new HashMap<String, String>(); // username , userType
    fillUsername(usernameAndType);
    myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(p))); // does not work.
}    
    
public static void fillHasmap(HashMap<String, UserContact> myHashMap) {
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        UserContact single = new UserContact();
        String username = "stack" + i;
        single.setUsername(username);
        single.setUserType("Client");
        single.setUserEmail("temp" + i + "@drop.me");
        myHashMap.put(username, single);
     }
}

public static void fillUsername(HashMap<String, String> usernameAndType) {
    String[] userType = {"Client","Business"};
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        String username = "stack" + i;
        Random r = new Random();
        int a = r.nextInt(2);
        usernameAndType.put(username, usertype[a]);
    }
}
```

The UserContact class is this one:

```
public class UserContact{
    private String username;
    private String userType;
    private String email;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }
    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email= email;
    }
}
```

I want to change all the userType of my UserContact using the one present in the usernameAndType hashmap.
To do It I have used:

```
myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(p)));
```

But It doensn't work, because I think that without saving it in another hashmap is pointless. So I have tried something like this but I can't compile it because I have an error:

```
myHashMap= myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(p))).collect(HashMap::getKey, HashMap::getValue, this::throwIllegalArgumentException, HashMap::new);
```

Cannot invoke collect(HashMap::getKey, HashMap::getValue, this::throwIllegalArgumentException, HashMap::new) on the primitive type void

I kwon that I can pass the usernameAndType Hashmap to the method fillHasmap and get the element directly using it, but there is really another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the contents of the two maps correctly, I think the following works as an update in place:

```
myHashMap
    .entrySet()
    .forEach(entry ->
        entry.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(entry.getKey())));
```

Even easier would be to use the following form:

```
myHashMap
    .forEach((key, value) -> 
        value.setUserType(usernameAndType.get(key)));
```

Comment: As I wrote, the myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(p))); don't change the usertype

Comment: @LizLamperouge - notice the equivalent code you should use is usernameAndType.get(p.getKey()) and not just usernameAndType.get(p). That is, you need to key on the username KEY, not use the map entry object.

Comment: change p with p.getKey works!!!! But I don't understand, what is p/entry in this case?

Comment: @LizLamperouge iterating through your myHashMap using foreach yields a Map.Entry<String, UserContact> each time. You have named this 'p'. So p.getValue() returns the UserContact value, and p.getKey() returns the String key. So, you need to get hold of the username key from the current Map.Entry using p.getKey(), to lookup in the userNameAndType map. Using just p would attempt to use a UserContact as a key in the second map, hence the compile time error you would have experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have getters for the `userType`, try this to create the usernameType hashMap.  If you want to modify the original hash map see my second example.

- this streams the entrySet of your first map.
- creates a new map with the key and the value being the `userType`.
- remember the `getValue()` returns a `UserContact` object so you need to  dereference it to get the `userType`

```
Map<String,String> usernameAndType = myHashMap
             .entrySet()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e->e.getValue().userType));
```

If you have getters for your fields, the you can change
`e->e.getValue().userType` to 
`e->e.getValue().getUserType()` or whatever you named it.

To use the information in the usernameAndType hash map to modify the objects in myHashMap, do the following:

NOTE: You should use a loop to do this because it is considered poor technique to modify external objects from within a stream.

```
for (Entry<String, UserContact> e : myHashMap.entrySet()) {
    UserContact uc = e.getValue();
    uc.setUserType(usernameAndType.get(e.getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with the code :

First (your code) :

```
myHashMap= myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(p))).collect(HashMap::getKey, HashMap::getValue, this::throwIllegalArgumentException, HashMap::new);
```

you are calling collect on a non stream. I wont point out the mistakes here but according to your implementation (at least how you'r trying to do it ). This should have been enough to change / mutate the value of the original map without having need to create a new one.

```
myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType("someuserType"));
```

here the p is a Map.Entry (key, value ), and the value is a UserContact so p.getValue() = UserContact then call a setter to the object

- **Answer : May be for a new map, you wanna do something like this:**

  ```
    Map<String,String> newMap = myHashMap.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserContact::getUsername,UserContact::getUserType));
  ```

**Shortcut to the above example would be:**

```
Map<String,String> newMap2 = myHashMap.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserContact::getUsername,UserContact::getUserType))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic requirement is to construct a new HashMap? Or to mutate the values present in the original HashMap?

If it is to mutate the values present in original HashMap.

```
myHashMap.values().stream().forEach(val -> val.setUserType(usernameAndType.get(val.getUserName())));
```

If you need to construct another HashMap with the updated one (Why?!), simply you can do this after the previous step.

```
Map<String,UserContact> myHashMapNew = new HashMap<>(myHashMap);
```

Comment: the myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(p -> p.getValue().setUserType(usernameAndType.get(p))); doesn't change the type of my user....